# How to say "black market" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, new-latin

How does one say "black market" in Latin?

[According to the *OED*](https://oed.com/view/Entry/19748), this word first originated in English in 1727.

Answer (score 12):

According to the Vatican's [*Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis, parvum verborum novatorum Léxicum*](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html#m):

> mercato nero [Italian]     ***[mercatūra](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=mercat%C5%ABra#lexicon) clandestīna*** [Latin]